# Is it possible to override the Session Cookie Lifetime found in the sys. config.?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cookie, administration

Is it possible to override the Session Cookie Lifetime found in the system configuration?

The reason I ask is because it appears that Magento is not honoring the value I set for Cookie Lifetime no matter what. This is an instance that MANY developers have had their hands in and it seems someone found a way to override it. Any thoughts?

Comment: After changing the value, have you cleared all the cache and restarted your web services to ensure the new value has taken effect?

Comment: Definitely. This is happening on local instances as well. Somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of `code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php` and make sure the file is used. If the lifetime is wrong, check where it is set.

Answer (score -2):

File

> code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php

```
public static function buildCookie()
        {
                require_once 'app/Mage.php';
                $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
                session_set_cookie_params(
                         self::getCookieLifetime()
                        ,self::getDefaultCookiePath()
//                      ,$request->getHttpHost() // commented out to fix double cookie problem.
                        ,'.domain.com' // added to fix double cookie problem.
                        ,false
                        ,true
                );
                session_name('frontend');
                session_start();
        }
```

Comment: Modifying core files is strongly in conflict with Magento best practices.

Comment: not best way to change core files.